# What methods to use to integrate $\sqrt{1+t^4}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have this integral to evaluate

$$\int^x_1 \sqrt{1+ t^4}\, dt$$

I have tried substitution, trig identity and integration by parts, I don't have any answer.

Can anyone explain the method I need to work this out?

---

Edit: I copied the following text from a now deleted answer by the OP in the hope that having it here may clarify and otherwise improve the question, JL.

It really is a problem that is asked to show that the function y = f (x) is a solution of the differential equation in this case would be

\begin{array}{rc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{4}} } \int ^{x}_{1}\sqrt{1+} t^{4}& dt
\end{array}

And the ec. Dif is $$y'+\frac{2x^{3}}{1+x^{4}} y=1$$

Comment: $\LaTeX$ hint:  the braces after \sqrt go around everything you want under the radical sign.  It may have been a typo.

Comment: Hint. Does the problem ask you to do this integral, or to differentiate something?

Comment: Yes, just another example of how not reading the question can lose loads of time and effort

Answer (score 5):

- The integral does not possess any elementary anti-derivative: see [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) for more information.
- It can be rewritten in terms of [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) or [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), by expanding 
   the integrand into its own [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and then reversing the order of summation and integration.

Answer (score 0):

When $x\geq1$ ,

$\int_1^x\sqrt{1+t^4}~dt$

$=\int_1^xt^2\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{t^4}}~dt$

$=\int_1^xt^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)t^{4n}}dt$

$=\int_1^x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{2-4n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}dt$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{3-4n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)(3-4n)}\right]_1^x$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n-3)x^{4n-3}}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n-3)}$

When $|x|\leq1$ ,

$\int_1^x\sqrt{1+t^4}~dt$

$=\int_1^x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{4n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}dt$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{4n+1}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)(4n+1)}\right]_1^x$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{4n+1}}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n+1)}$

When $x\leq-1$ ,

$\int_1^x\sqrt{1+t^4}~dt$

$=\int_{-1}^x\sqrt{1+t^4}~dt+\int_1^{-1}\sqrt{1+t^4}~dt$

$=\int_{-x}^1\sqrt{1+t^4}~dt-2\int_0^1\sqrt{1+t^4}~dt$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{3-4n}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)(3-4n)}\right]_{-x}^1-2\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{4n+1}}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)(4n+1)}\right]_0^1$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n-3)x^{4n-3}}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n-3)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n-1}(n!)^2(2n-1)(4n+1)}$