Why can't we evaluate this integral in terms of elementary functions$?$

Consider the integral $$\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^4}dx$$
Now this can easily be solved using a simple substitution $u=x^4$.

I want to know why any trigonometric or hyperbolic substitution, does not work in evaluating this. This seems a pretty simple integral but cannot be evaluated in elementary functions. What makes the calculation of this integral impossible in terms of elementary functions$?$ It resembles the $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ integral quite closely.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Well, $x^2\ne x^4$.  And the definite integral here can be expressed in terms of the Gamma function evaluated at $1/4$ and $3/4$.  I'm not sure what you're asking or expecting.

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x^4}dx = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-u} \frac{1}{4} u^{-3/4} ~du$$
That doesn't seem to simplify things very much.

@MarkViola yeah ik it can be expressed as gamma function...but that isn't an elementary function...I'm asking about the peculiar nature of this integral which seems pretty simple but is actually a terrifying one

I wouldn't call the Gamma function terrifying.  And why should the result be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Liouville's theorem states that only a limited number of elementary functions have an anti-derivative that can be expressed in elementary functions. This function is not one of them.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1265290/42969

Is it known that $\Gamma(1/4)$ is not algebraic?

@GEdgar I really don't get what you mean by algebraic?? Can you pls elaborate?

Not all integrals can be expressed as elementary functions. Liouville's theorem, among other things, limits what kind of functions have indefinite integrals expressible as elementary functions.

As you point out the $1-x^2$ integral nicely transforms into a trigonometric function by the pythagorean identity but when you evaluate $1-x^4$ you get $1-\cos^4x$ which doesn't trivialy transform into a nice trigonometric or hyperbolic function.
You could try to square $\cos^2x={1+\cos(2x)\over 2}$ and you will get an answer involving $\cos^2(2x)$ that you can use u-substitution on. But then we could just use u-substitution straight away. But to my knowledge there is no "clever" answer or theorem that says why a specific integral has no "nice" simplifications.

+1, specifically for the very last sentence in your posting.

I see...thanks for the insights

If you are asking about this definite integral the reason why there is no closed form in terms of elementary functions  is that no one was able to discover a closed form in terms of elementary functions for $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})$ see this, the integral can be found in terms of $\Gamma(\frac{1}{4})$

$$\Gamma(z) = (z-1)! = \int_0^ \infty e^{-t} t^{z-1} dt \ \ \  ;Re(z)>0 $$
$$B(a,b)= \int_0^1 t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1} dt = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
$$B(x+1,y)=\frac{x}{x+y}B(x,y)$$
$$\Gamma(a) \Gamma(1-a) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi a)}$$

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^4}dx= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 t^{\frac{1}{4}-1} (1-x^4)^{1+\frac 1 2 -1}= \frac{B\left(1+\frac{1}{2},\frac 1 4 \right)}{4}  $$
$$=\frac{2}{12}\cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac 1 4\right)}= \frac{2}{12}\cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac 1 4\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)} $$
$$=\frac{\sqrt {2}  \ \Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{12\sqrt{\pi}}$$
The question is equivalent to finding a closed form of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\int_0^ \infty e^{-t} t ^{-3/4}dt$
